# Rails MySQL Query: Difference Between Interpolation and?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I thought I saw somewhere that using the `?` escapes the query, to help prevent sql injection attacks, but I can't find any definitive answers.

What's the difference between the following 2 queries (with a variable of `name` defined previously):

`People.where("name = ?", name)`

and

`People.where('name = "#{name}"')`

Rails 3.2.1

Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the same thing, here on the [Active Record Query Interface Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-a-string-sql-fragment). Section 2.2 states about the latter method (passing the hash):

> > Putting the variable directly into the conditions string will pass the variable to the database as-is. This means that it will be an unescaped variable directly from a user who may have malicious intent.

Here is a link to the API for [build_where](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/build_where), which is called in the [Where](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) method. When a hash is passed into the method, it's passed directly to the database. When you use the former syntax ("name = ?", opts), the query is sanitized before the options are passed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 People.where("name = ?", name)

 This is secured. 

 People.where('name = "#{name}"')

 This is called sql injection and it's not secured.
```